# Why is UDF functions not visible in `show function status`?

Tags: mysql

I'm compiled and installed [udf_sys](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys), and it works:

```
mysql> select sys_exec("cp /etc/passwd /tmp");
+---------------------------------+
| sys_exec("cp /etc/passwd /tmp") |
+---------------------------------+
|                               0 |
+---------------------------------+
```

However, it's not visible in show function status:

```
mysql> show function status like '%sys_exec%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

It's totally weird, any ideas? I'm running MySQL 5.7

**EDIT**

Tried to use grep instead, and I got empty result

```
mysql -uroot -e 'show function status' | grep sys_exec
```

Comment: run just `show function status;` command and check any function name contain sys_exec .ithink  not, maybe function wrapped with another name

Comment: @MangeshAuti tried, see my update

Comment: `#define LIBVERSION "lib_mysqludf_sys version 0.0.3"` try `mysql -uroot -e 'show function status' | grep sys`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I got a bunch of unrelated mysql.sys functions. So I stopped grep and search in iTerm2, no match for sys_exec ...

Comment: Try: `SELECT \`name\` FROM \`mysql\`.\`func\`;`.